# Community detection in Networkx

Tags: python, igraph, networkx, modularity

I'm studying about detection communities in networks.

I'm use igraph and Python

For the optimal number of communities in terms of the modularity measure:

```
from igraph import *
karate = Nexus.get("karate")
cl = karate.community_fastgreedy()
cl.as_clustering().membership
```

For supply the desired number of communities:

```
from igraph import *
karate = Nexus.get("karate")
cl = karate.community_fastgreedy()
k=2
cl.as_clustering(k).membership
```

However, I like to do this using networkx. I know get optimal number of communities in terms of the modularity measure:

```
import community # --> http://perso.crans.org/aynaud/communities/
import fastcommunity as fg # --> https://networkx.lanl.gov/trac/ticket/245
import networkx as nx

g = nx.karate_club_graph()
partition = community.best_partition(g)
print "Louvain Modularity: ", community.modularity(partition, g)
print "Louvain Partition: ", partition

cl = fg.communityStructureNewman(g)
print "Fastgreed Modularity: ", cl[0]
print "Fastgreed Partition: ", cl[1]
```

But I can not get the desired number of communities. Are there some algorithm for this, using Networkx?

Comment: This is a very recent work but is extremely useful: https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.117.078301

Answer (score 5):

I'm also new to networkx and igraph, I used Gephi, an data visualization tool/software. And it has the same community detection algorithm as the one in networkx you are now using. Specifically, in http://perso.crans.org/aynaud/communities/

> It uses the louvain method described in Fast unfolding of communities in large networks, Vincent D Blondel, Jean-Loup Guillaume, Renaud Lambiotte, Renaud Lefebvre, Journal of Statistical Mechanics: Theory and Experiment 2008(10), P10008 (12pp)

You can not get desired number of communities, as I know, there're two ways worth to try:

- Use Gephi. You can use gephi and there's a parameter called `resolution` that would change the size of the community you get.
- Use NetworkX. This time, we may not use `best_partition(G)` any more. But use `partition_at_level(dendrogram, level)` , I guess this might help.

Check the [source code](https://bitbucket.org/taynaud/python-louvain/src/147f0973771485ce1b45c89c1e2766f94efaa4d4/community/__init__.py?at=default) here for more info.

Comment: NetworkX doesn't have community detection. It's all coming from `community`, which builds upon NetworkX. More specifically, `best_partition()` is `community.best_partition()`.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps I am misunderstanding you, but if you would like the number of communities output by the NetworkX implementation of the best_partition algorithm, just note that best_partition(G) gives a dictionary with nodes as keys and their partition number as value.

You can count the number of unique values in a dictionary like this (likely not optimal):

```
dict = {'a':1,'b':1,'c':2,'d':1,'e':3,'f':4,'g':5}
count=list(set([i for i in dict.values()]))
print count
print len(count)
```

With result

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
5
```

Comment: I think the OP is interested in stating a priori the number of communities to detect, not in receiving the optimal number of communities