# How to identify loosely-connected components of a graph

Tags: algorithm, graph

Imagine that a graph has two relatively densely connected components that are only connected to each other by relatively few edges. How can I identify the components? I don't know the proper terminology, but the intuition is that a relatively densely connected subgraph is hanging onto another subgraph by a few threads. I want to identify these clumps that are only loosely connected to the rest of the graph.

Comment: Tim Roughgarden's [lectures on minimum cuts](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zfc1iUQGy48&amp;list=PLLH73N9cB21W1TZ6zz1dLkyIm50HylGyg) might give a good introduction.

Answer (score 2):

If your graph represents a real-world system, this task is called *community detection*. You'll find many articles about that, starting with [Fortunato's review (2010)](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0370157309002841). He describes, amongst others, the min-cut based methods mentioned in the earlier answers.

There're also many posts on SO, such as :

- [Are there implementations of algorithms for community detection in graphs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5822265/are-there-implementations-of-algorithms-for-community-detection-in-graphs)
- [What are the differences between community detection algorithms in igraph?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9471906/what-are-the-differences-between-community-detection-algorithms-in-igraph)
- [Community detection in Networkx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22070196/community-detection-in-networkx)

People in Cross Validated also talk about community detection :

- [How to do community detection in a weighted social network/graph?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2948/how-to-do-community-detection-in-a-weighted-social-network-graph)
- [How to find communities?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/82804/how-to-find-communities)

Finally, there's a proposal in Area 51 for a new [Network Science](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/61500/network-science) site, which would be more directly related to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want sparsest cut instead of min cut -- unless you can identify several nodes in a component, min cuts have a tendency to be very unbalanced when the degrees are small. One of the common approaches to sparsest cut is to compute an eigenvector of the graph's Laplacian and threshold it.

Answer (score 0):

The answer might be somewhat general, but you could could try to model your problem as a flow problem and generate a minimum cut; see [here](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max-Flow-Min-Cut-Theorem). The edges could be bidirectional with capacity `1`, and a resulting cut would maybe yield the desired partition?